# How to add a search filter to ComboBox

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I have a ComboBox in QML which holds over 2000 items. There are too many items to scroll to the last element. How can I add add a search filter for ComboBox? When I type letters, the matching results should show in the list. Alternatively, can I raise the mouse wheel speed to make scrolling faster?

**I FOUND SOLUTION LIKE:**

```
    ComboBox {
                id:trCombo
                model:combotr.datalist
                textRole: "value"
                anchors.fill: parent
                currentIndex:-1;



                contentItem: Text {
                    leftPadding: 0
                    rightPadding: trCombo.indicator.width + trCombo.spacing

                    text:trCombo.currentIndex==-1 ? "":trCombo.model[trCombo.currentIndex].value
                    font: trCombo.font
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    elide: Text.ElideRight
                }

                popup: T.Popup {
                    id:mpopup
                    y: trCombo.height - (trCombo.visualFocus ? 0 : 1)

                    width: trCombo.width
                    implicitHeight: listview.contentHeight
                    topMargin: 6
                    bottomMargin: 6

                // focus: true
                    closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose

                    contentItem: Item {


                        Column
                        {
                        anchors.fill: parent
                        spacing: 5
                        TextField
                        {

                        placeholderText: "arama yapın"
                        width: trCombo.width
                        height: dp(35)
                    // color: "red"
                        focus:true
                        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhNoPredictiveText;

                        onTextChanged:{
                            //console.log("degisiyor");
                            process.filtertr(text);
                        }

                        onAccepted:{
                        //  console.log("Tasarım Bitti");
                            isfinished(true);
                        //  text="";


                        }




                        }

                        ListView {
                        id: listview
                        clip: true
                        model: trCombo.popup.visible ? trCombo.delegateModel : null
                        currentIndex: trCombo.highlightedIndex
                        width: trCombo.width
                        height:dp(500)


                        Rectangle {



                            z: 10
                            parent: listview
                            width: listview.width
                            height: listview.height
                            color: "transparent"
                            border.color: "#bdbebf"
                            layer.smooth: true
                        }

                        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
                    }

                    }
                }

                    background: Rectangle {  }

                    onClosed: {
                    if(!flag)
                    {
                        mpopup.open();
                    }

                    else
                    flag=false;
                    }


                }


                delegate: ItemDelegate {
                    width: trCombo.width
                    text: trCombo.textRole ? (Array.isArray(trCombo.model) ? modelData[trCombo.textRole] : model[trCombo.textRole]) : modelData
                    font.weight: trCombo.currentIndex === index ? Font.DemiBold : Font.Normal
                    highlighted: trCombo.highlightedIndex == index

                    onClicked: {
                        isfinished(true);
                    }
                }



                onCurrentIndexChanged: {

                    if(currentIndex!=-1)
                    {
                        var sqlid=model[currentIndex].sqlid;
                        combotr.getsqlid(sqlid,1,Query.SelectSubParam,Query.Subq,"TRC",1);
                        TaskResult.taskresult.HatBilgisi_TR=sqlid ;
                        trsCombo.enabled=true;


                    }

                    else
                        trsCombo.enabled=false;

                    trsCombo.currentIndex=-1;
                }


        }
```

Comment: `QtQuick.Controls 1` or `QtQuick.Controls 2`?

Comment: A combobox with 2000 elements is close to useless. You want a line edit with a completer. (I've got no idea if Qt Quick Controls have something like that).

Comment: @Mitch , I use QtQuick.Controls 2

Comment: Combobox is currently not editable in controls 2. Plus, it would be better to use a `TextField` with a `ListView` as proposed by @peppe. AFAIK there's no built-in support for this but that would be a nice addition to the new controls.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo , Thanks for your solution. I need both combobox and search. How to increse scrool speed for alternatiy :)

Comment: Why do you *need* the combobox from QtQuick.Controls? Use a `ListView` to build your own, custom combobox, with what ever search functionality you want.

Comment: Why don't you though ? A `TextField` with a `ListView` is basically an editable `ComboBox` without the popup functionality. I believe you can make a `ComoboBox` editable just by setting it's `contentItem` to a `TextField`. Next you need to implement the search. Maybe that can be done with my SortFilterProxyModel lib : https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel

Comment: A completer popup is on the todo-list (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51004) but I don't know when we have time to implement it.

Comment: Please check the last answer, @DJ.Yosemite

Answer (score 1):

I customized the combobox and use it as a searchable combobox, the result of which is shown in the image below.

[image: searchableCombobox]

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import MyAPP

    /*! ***********************************************************************************************
     * SearchableComboBox provides the possibility to search on model items.
     * ************************************************************************************************/
    
    ComboBox {
        id: control
    
        /* Property Declarations
         * ****************************************************************************************/
        property var imodel
    
        /* Object Properties
         * ****************************************************************************************/
    
         //! Filter (based on action names) conditions with filter text.
        model: imodel.filter(condition => {
                                   if(filterConditionText.text.length > 0)
                            return condition[control?.textRole]?.includes(filterConditionText.text)
                         return true
                             });
    
        popup: Popup {
            y: control.height - 1
            width: control.width
            implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight
            padding: 1
    
            contentItem: Item {
                anchors.fill: parent
    
                TextArea {
                    id: filterConditionText
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: parent.bottom
    
                    focus: false
                    leftPadding: 12
    
                    selectByMouse: true
                    hoverEnabled: true
    
                    wrapMode: TextEdit.WrapAnywhere
                    placeholderText: qsTr("Filter")
                    background: Rectangle {
                        color: "#1c2127"
                    }
    
                    //! Bottom indicator
                    Rectangle {
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        anchors.left: parent.left
                        anchors.right: parent.right
    
                        anchors.bottomMargin: 12
                        height: 1
                        color: filterConditionText.activeFocus ? filterConditionText.selectionColor :
                                                                 AppStyle.inputBoxGray
                    }
                }
    
                //! List view to show/select items
                ListView {
                    clip: true
                    anchors.left: parent.left
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.top: filterConditionText.bottom
    
                    implicitHeight: contentHeight
                    model: control.popup.visible ? control.delegateModel : null
                    currentIndex: control.highlightedIndex
    
                    ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
                }
    
    
            }
    
        }
    
        //! Specified item delegates
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            width: control.width
            height: control.height
    
            palette.text: control.palette.text
            palette.highlightedText: control.palette.highlightedText
    
            contentItem: Text {
                text: modelData?.[textRole]
    
                font.family: "Roboto"
                font.pointSize: 12
                font.weight: 400
                color: "white"
                elide: Text.ElideRight
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
    
            background: Rectangle {
                color: highlighted ? Qt.lighter(AppStyle.inputBoxGray, 1.1) : "#1c2127"
            }
    
            highlighted: control.highlightedIndex === index
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
  //! Combobox to view/select actions in any nodes
    SearchableComboBox {
        id: actionComboBox
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: deleteBotton.left
        height: 40
        imodel: actions
        currentIndex: actions.indexOf(condition)
        textRole: "name"
        onCurrentValueChanged: {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a quite similar Problem, however I have had a ListView and a Textbox it should be applyable to your Problem.

First there is no (easy) Possibility to Filter a Model in QML, but i ran over a project that solves this: [(QML)SortFilterProxyModel](https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel)

I'm afraid i cannot try it currently but you could use this Model as follows:

```
import SortFilterProxyModel 0.1

ComboBox {
    textRole: "value"
    model: SortFilterProxyModel {
        id: filteredModel
        sourceModel: selectionDialog.model
        filterRoleName: parent.textRole
        filterPattern: parent.text // not pretty shure if this is correct,
        // sorry I currently cannot test it, use the inserted Text of the Combobox
        filterCaseSensitivity: Qt.CaseInsensitive
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you. Feel free to ask if there is something unclear.

Comment: SortFilterProxyModel is your owns or QT

Comment: It's the Model from Qt with a nice QML-Interface. I'ts not my work I only found, used it for my project and liked the Interface, because I think it's something thats missing in the QML-World.